# Why did Detective Ward want crack warrant for the PO box in Jersey?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, the-international

In *The International (2009)*, Detective Ward said this to Interpol Agent Louis and Detective
Iggy. Actually all three guys looking  for hitman for IBBS Bank.
This Hitman is patient at Dr Isaacson. While checking patient
files, one patient gave post office as address and phone number
which is dead.

[image]

> I'll put a call in to Hubby, have her run it down. See if we can't get
>   a **crack warrant for the P.O. Box in Jersey**.

Hubby means Female Detective Hubbard.

So, why did Detective Ward want crack warrant for the PO box in Jersey?